# Multiply all values of multiple tuples within a list (python)

Tags: python, list, numpy, multiplication

I have a list with multiple tuples inside, i.e.

```
my_list = [(1,2,3),(5,2,1),(3,3,3)]
```

I need to multiply values inside of every tuple within this list to have something like: `my_list_results = [6,10,27]`

I tried:

```
import numpy
my_list_results = list(numpy.product(my_list, axis = 1))
```

but some of the values somehow return as negative. The list is quite large (over 10000 items), so I am not sure if a for loop will be a good solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[ 6, 10, 27]` as the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, correct, my apologies for confusion

Comment: actually, the `tolist()` conversion worked perfectly. 
I am trying to count a standard deviation of that list right now; however, it is so large the console freezes. Do you have any suggestions for that? I am using: 
    `std = statistics.stdev(my_list_results)`

Comment: Can you mention any tuple for ehich it is giving wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy I changed axis to `axis=-1`. That should fix the negative numbers issue. If it still doesn't work create a function that will multiply it for you.